# how output of print(print_board(board)) is printed like a matrix but not like a list or line from top to bottom?

Tags: python, for-loop, arraylist

```
board = []
for i in range(5):
  board.append(['O'] * 5)

def print_board(board_in):
  for x in board_in:
    print (x)

print(board)    
print(print_board(board))
```

Comment: what do you want the output to look like? have you tried `pprint.pprint` which prints it as matrix over multiple lines to look pretty.

Comment: also since `print_board` is doing printing it is returning `None` so if you print the output of it it will print `None` at the end, you can just call it like `print_board(board)` without `print()` around it.

Comment: Please read [mre].

Answer (score 1):

`print(board)` will just print `board` in the standard "list of lists" format:

```
>>> print(board)
[['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
```

`print_board(board)` will execute the code in your `print_board` function, which prints each list (in the standard representation of a list) on its own line:

```
>>> print_board(board)
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
```

The `print_board` function returns `None`, so if you call the function *and* print the result of it, then that will print `None` at the end:

```
>>> print(print_board(board))
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
None
```

If you don't want to use the normal list representation in your output, you could use `join` to generate your own strings from the list elements:

```
>>> print("\n".join(' '.join(c for c in row) for row in board))
O O O O O
O O O O O
O O O O O
O O O O O
O O O O O
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your question, it is printed like a matrix because `print` adds new line by default.

```
def print_board(board_in):
  for x in board_in:
    print (x)
```

You are printing each member (i.e.['O'] * 5) and a newline (added py print by default)